# Show that $K(x,y)=(2^{nk}\mathcal{F}^{-1}(2^kx))_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a singular kernel

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space, singular-integrals

I want to show that for a bump function $\psi$ with support in the annulus $\{\frac{1}{2}\leq\vert x\vert\leq2\}$ the kernel $K(x,y)=(2^{nk}\mathcal{F}^{-1}\psi(2^k(x-y)))_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a vector valued singular kernel, i.e. it must be shown that $\Vert K(x,y)\Vert_{\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})}\leq C\frac{1}{\vert x-y\vert^n}$ with a constant C depending only on n.
Unfortunately I'm not able to show this, so I'm hoping for your help.
greets Lukas

Comment: Typically, one assumes a smoothness condition (i.e. Hormander's condition) on the kernel $K$ as well. Otherwise, you can't directly apply the Calderon-Zygmund theorem once you have an $L^{2}$ estimate.

Comment: In the lecture notes I'm reading it has been proven that $K(x,y)$ is a Calderon-Zygmund Operator but the proof that K is singular was left to the reader, and that should be possible without any further assumptions

Comment: thank you! for the convergence of the sum $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}2^{2k(n-N)}$ (you probably mistyped this) you once need to choose N greater than than n and once smaller than n, because you sum over $\mathbb{Z}$, don't you? If I do so I get $\Vert\overrightarrow{K}(x)\Vert_{\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\ell^2}\lesssim_{N}\frac{1}{\vert x\vert^N}$ for some $N$ not necessarily equal to $n$, but I need the n-th power here. Finally how ist $\Vert \nabla\overrightarrow{K}(x)\Vert_{\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\ell^2}$ defined? I can't find any information about the gradient of a $\ell^2$-sized function

Comment: Yes, I edited my answer to correct this. Take $N=n+1$; this isn't an issue... If you don't like derivatives of vector-valued functions, just verify that $\|K(x)-K(x-y)\|_{\ell^{2}}$ satisfies a Holder condition or the weaker Hormander condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you mean a $C_{c}^{\infty}$ function by "bump function." I am going to change your notation for convenience: I will write $\widehat{\psi}$ where you have written $\psi$. For each $k$, set $\psi_{k}(x):=2^{kn}\psi(2^{k}x)$. For each $x$, define an operator-valued ($\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$) by $\vec{K}(x)=(\psi_{k}(x))_{k}$. Since $\psi$ is Schwartz, we have that

$$|\psi(x)|\lesssim_{N}(1+|x|)^{-N}, \quad |\nabla\psi(x)|\lesssim_{N}(1+|x|)^{-N}$$
for $N>0$ arbitrarily large (say $N=n+1$). The size condition follows from

\begin{align*}
\|\vec{K}(x)\|_{\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\ell^{2}}&=\left(\sum_{2^{k}|x|<1}|\psi(x)|^{2}+\sum_{2^{k}|x|\geq 1}|\psi_{k}(x)|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\sum_{2^{k}|x|\leq 1}|\psi_{k}(x)|+\sum_{2^{k}|x|>1}|\psi_{k}(x)|\\
&\lesssim\sum_{2^{k}|x|<1}2^{kn}+\sum_{2^{k}|x|\geq 1}2^{kn}(|2^{k}x|)^{-N}\\
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that $\ell^{1}$-norm dominates $\ell^{2}$-norm. Let $k_{0}$ and $k_{0}'$ respectively denote the maximal and minimal integers such that $2^{k_{0}}<|x|^{-1}$ and $2^{k_{1}}\geq|x|^{-1}$. Then the last expression above is majorized by
$$\lesssim_{n}2^{k_{0}n}+2^{k_{1}(n-N)}|x|^{-N}\lesssim_{n}|x|^{-n}+2^{k_{1}(n-N)}|x|^{-N}\lesssim |x|^{-n}$$

by our choice of $N$. You said you didn't to verify smoothness, so I won't do it. By a modification of the argument given, you can verify that $\vec{K}$ satisfies the Hormander smoothness condition.

Comment: thank you very much!!! You really helped me out! It'd be awesome if you could also show me how the Hölder condition is proved! Thanks!

Comment: I've managed to show it myself. No more help needed here ;)